# Rescale Chart in Vega-Lite

Tags: vega-lite, vega

We have this dataset which we want to visualize with Vega/Vega-Lite

```
{
   "$schema":"https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v4.13.json",
   "description":"Testing",
   "width":"container",
   "height":350,
   "autosize":{
      "type":"fit",
      "contains":"padding"
   
},
   "layer":[
      {
         "data":{
            "values":[
               {
                  "stepid":"4444",
                  "stepname":"Name1",
                  "serialnumber":"SN3444444",
                  "lowval":45000,
                  "highval":45500,
                  "resultdecimal":45466
               
},
               {
                  "stepid":"4444",
                  "stepname":"Name1",
                  "serialnumber":"SN3444445",
                  "lowval":45000,
                  "highval":45500,
                  "resultdecimal":45433
               
},
               {
                  "stepid":"4444",
                  "stepname":"Name1",
                  "serialnumber":"SN3444446",
                  "lowval":45000,
                  "highval":45500,
                  "resultdecimal":45400
               
},
               {
                  "stepid":"4444",
                  "stepname":"Name1",
                  "serialnumber":"SN3444447",
                  "lowval":45000,
                  "highval":45500,
                  "resultdecimal":45422
               
},
               {
                  "stepid":"4444",
                  "stepname":"Name1",
                  "serialnumber":"SN3444448",
                  "lowval":45000,
                  "highval":45500,
                  "resultdecimal":45403
               
},
               {
                  "stepid":"4444",
                  "stepname":"Name1",
                  "serialnumber":"SN3444449",
                  "lowval":45000,
                  "highval":45500,
                  "resultdecimal":45422
               
}
            
]
         
},
         "layer":[
            {
               "mark":{
                  "type":"line",
                  "strokeWidth":3,
                  "point":{
                     "size":45,
                     "filled":true
                  
},
                  "interpolate":"monotone"
               
},
               "encoding":{
                  "x":{
                     "field":"serialnumber",
                     "type":"ordinal",
                     "axis":{
                        "labelAngle":-70,
                        "title":"Selected Tests",
                        "titleFontSize":10
                     
}
                  
},
                  "y":{
                     "field":"resultdecimal",
                     "type":"quantitative",
                     "axis":{
                        "title":"Teststeps in selected Tests",
                        "titleFontSize":10
                     
}
                  
},
                  "tooltip":[
                     {
                        "field":"serialnumber",
                        "type":"ordinal"
                     
},
                     {
                        "field":"resultdecimal",
                        "type":"quantitative"
                     
}
                  
]
               
}
            
},
            {
               "mark":"rule",
               "encoding":{
                  "y":{
                     "field":"highval"
                  
},
                  "stroke":{
                     "value":"#FF0000"
                  
}
               
}
            
},
            {
               "mark":"rule",
               "encoding":{
                  "y":{
                     "field":"lowval"
                  
},
                  "stroke":{
                     "value":"#FF0000"
                  
}
               
}
            
}
         
]
      
}
   
]
}
```

Everything works fine but the scaling on the y-axis is not too optimal

[image]

Is it possible to rescale y-axis so it is more scaled-into-view based on lowval and highval e.g. like this one?

[image]

Furthermore is it possible to write the "lowval" and "highval" values on top of the lines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can control the y-axis domain using the `scale.domain` property:

```
"y": {
  "field": "resultdecimal",
  "type": "quantitative",
  "axis": {
    "title": "Teststeps in selected Tests",
    "titleFontSize": 10
  },
  "scale": {
    "domain": [45000, 45500]
  }
},
```

Adding that to your chart, results in this ([view in editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-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-cPv6mSzc6HwwBdKogGp1PFNEDIHQAa3aKTSTmEngFOjYq7gAHV7I5UNJ1Dg2B5MO0YvFXuosoJBHBjZgdD1ZzevFeaoMnAQZQ2CiXdZzgJQXDKSx2gAD3aLI4EEY0bXFNsHWsTd5jYHRoKVcJYJoQpUFAGpdkEABBSxXzQfgXQeQxMBog4kOZQYNAAAjMAZCnURjXwAMVcfY4nSSQQgqWdkgQmgkJQrUS3Ha4+NSeYAEcGCQPI6FaGhSGsJBCOIpI6GYkBuMwREIA4jwOOTV8oHYrjzF4kB+LgIS8hEh9UHE2doC6dJmjYZAPEaW4VVUGl7hnWcojYH59D6EBEOQpxkzQ1N6hUrd0BwvDri5VL5NHQN8Lc1SnA0rTGN0-SKliqtlyQNcnE-Gj1AgqDynaaSSJS2S0vQAcXn8j8DyCjouh6JwAGIBIElUQhASSuRXdd0HahJOsgthoKsfq+tAYrtxJJUxv3Q92iuGb0HmxaVRWySZxnIA)):
[image]

Comment: can i set this value dynamically? meaning i've to set it with every new dataset i'm loading to a different value "highval" and "lowval"

Comment: in case somebody needs to set the scale.domain dynamic - this is how it works for me:  vegaspc.layer[0].layer[0].encoding.y.scale.domain=[jsret.limitlow,jsret.limithigh];